# Will this condition be true?

Tags: matrices

Let $X,Y,Z$ be $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries and  $\phi$ be a defined as $$X \phi Y=\frac{1}{2}(XY+YX).$$

Then, is $$X\phi(Y\phi Z)=X\phi Y+X\phi Z?$$

Please explain (new to matrices).

Comment: Why should it? This is just a random function in my textbook only for matrices. @copper.hat

Comment: Actually, $X\phi(Y+Z)=X\phi Y+X\phi Z$, so there might be a typo.

Comment: Take the matrices to be of the form $a I$. Then $(3I) \phi (3I) = 9I$, $(3I) \phi ((3I)  \phi (3I))= 27 I \neq 18 I$. My point was to try checking on simple stuff first, diagonal matrices commute so the computation is particularly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X\phi(Y\phi Z)=\frac{1}{2}X\phi(YZ+ZY)=\frac{1}{4}(XYZ+XZY+YZX+ZYX)$$

and $$X\phi Y=\frac{1}{2}(XY+YX) $$
$$X\phi Z=\frac{1}{2}(XZ+ZX) $$

So definitely, This condition ain't true